# Audit.NET CustomFields keeping value between requests

Tags: audit.net

I tried to use these two ways to write a customfield and it is recording correctly, but it is keeping customfields between requests

```
public class LoggerAudit : ILoggerAudit
{
    public void AddOnSavingAction(string key, object value)
    {
        Configuration.AddOnSavingAction(scope =>
        {
            scope.SetCustomField(key, value);
            //scope.Event.CustomFields.Remove(key);
            //scope.Event.CustomFields.Add(key, value);
        });
    }
}
```

For example:
In the first request my webapi recorded the customfield 'field-A', but in the second request my webapi, there was no need to write this customfield, but it was kept in scope and consequently in my json

I tried this setting, but it didn't work

```
.WithAction(action =>
{                    
    action.OnEventSaved(scope => scope.Event.CustomFields = new Dictionary<string, object>());                    
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [custom actions](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET#custom-actions) attached with `AddOnSavingAction` / `OnEventSaved` are globally attached and will execute for each and all the events before saving or after saving occurs (respectively), so you should attach each action just once.

But your use case looks like you don't have a way to derive the custom field value from the audit scope, so a custom action will not be useful.

Also I guess you are using `Audit.WebApi` extension. If that's the case, you won't need a custom action to add a custom field, since you can access the `AuditScope` with the provided [extension methods](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/03617192e5ca3c005fbd5a46f26077a47e4d5d12/src/Audit.WebApi/ApiControllerExtensions.cs#L67) directly on your controllers or in any place where you can get the current `HttpContext`, for example:

```
using Audit.WebApi;

[AuditApi]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get(string id)
    {
       //...
       var auditScope = this.GetCurrentAuditScope();
       auditScope.SetCustomField("MyField", Guid.NewGuid());
       //...
    }
}
```

or just

```
private void SetCustomField(HttpContext context, string key, object value)
{
    var auditScope = context.GetCurrentAuditScope();
    auditScope.SetCustomField(key, value);
}
```

Comment: As I am creating these custom fields in my business layer, I will then have to return this data to my webapi to add.

Thank you